# getting css content and then resolving image references of external css files for Link Validator

Tags: java, css, web-applications, jsoup

I am  creating a Link Validator that takes a seed page and validates all the links in that domain.  For example: http://www.example.com/ it should validate all the links which are part of example.com.

I have four kind of files:

1. Content Pages
2. Images
3. CSS
4. Javascript files

Now I am using JSOUP Library for Content Pages, Images and Javascript Files. 
For CSS which are external the problem is I want to get the content and then get all the selectors where it has URL reference like

`background-image : url('images.png');
border-image: url('border.png');`

so how do I resolve the URL of these images to absolute URL. I think the JSOUP directory does not provide any functionality related to CSS Selectors and resolving their value as absolute URL.

Yes, I can do tedious string manipulation but I think it will be error-prone. So I was thinking about using something built-in.

I hope I made myself clear. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will take that much string manipulation, just append the url with a slash and the css reference. And if its got a ../ you remove all characters until "/" I dont know of anything built-in, sorry. Also make sure that you do these images first, before your link validator "clicks" on any internal links, thereby altering the url.

Comment: okay thanks for your reply. I think then I have to use primitive functions like indexOf and all that.. :)

Comment: you can use a url class like this which has everything I need so for example.
`URL myURL = new URL ("http://loans-dev.boa.starcomworldwide.com/res/css/styles.css");
   URL myNewURL = new URL (myURL, "/res/img/nanToggleBG.png");`